# JIRA SOAP Filter Create

Tags: api, soap, jira, jira-plugin

I need to create a new filter on a JIRA server added to favourite filters so to be able to use the
getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit() function.  I cannot use getIssuesFromJqlSearch() because there is the necessity to downloads Issues in separate arrays.

Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it in Jira prior to version 5.0:

- You can manually create filters and set them as favourite for users.
  Here is a link to the help file - http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=267257855
- There is also a way of extending SOAP API by using [RPC endpoint plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/RPC+Endpoint+Plugin+Module)

It is possible to do what you want via REST API for Jira 5.0

```
The request would be something like:
http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=status=open&startAt=2&maxResults=2
```

REST API Documentation:

[JIRA 5.0-rc1 REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs)

[JIRA REST API Example - Query issues](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues)

Comment: ok..but its impossible way to solve that problem..i need to have this  done from API.. my intentions are not to create filter directly but to download array of issues separately and they are filtered somehow, for example: all unassigned, problem is that this is partially possible because SearchTerms are not so advanced as JQL and does not allow us to ask some(as above), is there function for JQL but that downloads the whole array of issues, i have no clue what to do now..

Comment: Hi, i have solved my problem of downloading issues in separate arrays by using getIssuesByJQL() and in query i just have added sorting by updated, so allows me to get certain time and add it to next query. For example: updated > 'someDate' And Project = someProject order by updated